# Redigo: Invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference while attempting to connect to pool

Tags: go, redis, connection-pooling, redigo

> Redis Connecting.....! panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or
>   nil pointer dereference [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x40154b]
>   goroutine 1 [running]: runtime.panic(0x52c6e0, 0x6b6348)
>   /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6
>   main.func·001(0xc21005102c, 0x0, 0x4bcd4c, 0x1)
>   /home/vinay10949/redischeck/redischeck.go:21 +0x10b
>   github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).get(0xc210051000, 0x0,
>   0xc2100378f0, 0x42dbdf, 0x7fbe9c177070)
>   /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis/pool.go:250
>   +0x3a2 github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*Pool).Get(0xc210051000, 0x1, 0x1)   > /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis/pool.go:150
>   +0x27 main.main() /home/
>
> vinay10949/redischeck/redischeck.go:29 +0x13e

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
    //"reflect"
)

var (
    redisAddress   = flag.String("10.12.2.121", "10.12.2.121:6379", "Address to the Redis server")
    maxConnections = flag.Int("max-connections", 10, "Max connections to Redis")
)

func main() {

    //Redis Connection
    redisPool := redis.NewPool(func() (redis.Conn, error) {

        con, err := redis.Dial("tcp", *redisAddress)
        con.Do("SELECT", 1)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return con, err
    }, *maxConnections)

    fmt.Println("Redis Connecting...!")
    con := redisPool.Get()
    status, errStatus := con.Do("SET", "Name", "BookMyShow")
    if errStatus != nil {
        fmt.Println(errStatus)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Redis Connected")
    }
    statusInsertion, _ := redis.String(status, errStatus)
    fmt.Println("Status of Insertion :" + statusInsertion)
    value, _ := redis.String(con.Do("GET", "Name"))
    fmt.Println("Value Retrieved : " + value)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
con, err := redis.Dial("tcp", *redisAddress)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
con.Do("SELECT", 0) //Select 0 for Nutcracker
```

Answer (score 5):

You are making the mistake of checking for an error **after** using the returned value:

```
con, err := redis.Dial("tcp", *redisAddress)
con.Do("SELECT", 1) // Here you are using con which most likely is nil
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Rearrange the code to:

```
con, err := redis.Dial("tcp", *redisAddress)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
con.Do("SELECT", 1) // con should be used after checking for errors
```